# Sql Cursor Knowledge

Tags: sql, database

Suppose I have a table with a single column (`Food`) like this:

```
FOOD
--------
Pizza
Milk 
Chicken
```

I know how to start a cursor while selecting this column, but how do I change each row every time I fetch it. For example, suppose I have a variable called `@Food` of `nvarchar(MAX)` type.

In the cursor, I want to `Fetch next into @Food`. How do I change the `@Food` variable that I have fetched and place the changed string instead of the original string in the column (such as changing 'Pizza' to 'Raspberry' for example)?

Comment: don't use a cursor to solve this...

Comment: I have used this question as a basic example. The real table has close to a thousand rows, where the actual editing depends upon the format of every field. Hence, I need a cursor.

Comment: 99 times out of a 100, a cursor is slower and more complicated than using a set based statement. Period. A thousand rows is nothing. 1 billion rows is a lot....

Comment: what dbms? Some provide "update" functionality, however updating the db using the data you have fetched is always available. That said your reason why you need a cursor does not appear to be valid.

Comment: Can I use an update and execute different update statements for different cases? These different cases would correspond to the different formats of hte fields in the column.

Comment: Especially if your table has thousands of rows, then you should **avoid cursors** at all costs! Stop thinking in loops and procedural, row-by-agonizing-row approaches - SQL is **set-based** - use its power!

Comment: Please also state which DBMS you are using (Oracle, Postgres, ...)

Comment: Probably, but you still haven't said which DBMS, and based on what you've stated, you don't require a cursor anyway. They are a tool of last resort, slightly better than sucking all your data onto a client, manipulating it and then pushing it back up.

Answer (score 0):

I'll suggest this as a general statement since you didn't identify your specific database vendor.

Using a cursor to copy a value into a variable does just that. It makes a local copy of the value. Changing @Food won't change the value in the row that the cursor retrieved. You will need to issue an update statement on the FOOD table.